# Error 1054 - Service did not respond in Timely Fashion - C# Application

Tags: c#, service, saas

Im having a problem installing my service application. When I'm running my debug mode it all works correctly and all the logical stuff works. I've written service applications before and comparing the two there is little difference between this one and a working one. Thanks in advance for any help on my code:

```
 class MainClass : ServiceBase
{
    ABCSQLCon _SQLCon = new ABCSQLCon();
    private int cycleTime = 0;

    private delegate void processError(String errorMessage);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #if(!DEBUG)
            ServiceBase.Run(new MainClass());
        #else
            MainClass service = new MainClass();
            service.OnStart(new string[0]);
        #endif
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        addToLog("Testing SQL Connection...", "Log");
        cycleTime = _SQLCon.sleepTime;
        addToLog("Sleep Time has been set...", "Log");
        if (_SQLCon.testSQLConnection())
        {
            addToLog("Connection to SQL Database succeeded", "Log");
           // queryThread();

            //not neccessary to make applicated multithreaded yet.
            addToLog("Starting Query Thread...", "Log");
            ThreadStart queryCycle = new ThreadStart(queryThread);
            Thread qThread = new Thread(queryCycle);
            qThread.Start();
        }
    }

    private void startProgram()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }

    public MainClass()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "ABCSQL Engine";
    }
```

Ah I found the problem now, the sql connection test was just a quick open and close job but what I didn't see or realise was where I was initializing that _SQLCON object.
I've moved that to my method and works fine now. Happy days, thanks for the answers as it helped me look in the place I wasnt looking. x

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is - it's not clear in your question.

Comment: testSQLConnection() is probably taking too long to complete. The Service Control Manager only gives you a short time to complete the `OnStart` method before it deduces that it has hung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a best practise to call to methods on a different thread then the service thread to avoid the blocking of the service thread

```
public void MyMethod()
{
        addToLog("Testing SQL Connection...", "Log");
        cycleTime = _SQLCon.sleepTime;
        addToLog("Sleep Time has been set...", "Log");
        if (_SQLCon.testSQLConnection())
        {
            addToLog("Connection to SQL Database succeeded", "Log");
           // queryThread();

            //not neccessary to make applicated multithreaded yet.
            addToLog("Starting Query Thread...", "Log");
            ThreadStart queryCycle = new ThreadStart(queryThread);
            Thread qThread = new Thread(queryCycle);
            qThread.Start();
        }

}

 private Thread _myThread;
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
        ThreadStart threadStart = MyMethod;
         _myThread = new Thread(threadStart);
         _myThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Ah I found the problem now, the sql connection test was just a quick open and close job but what I didn't see or realise was where I was initializing that _SQLCON object.
I've moved Initilization of _SQLCON to my method and works fine now. Happy days, thanks for the answers as it helped me look in the place I wasnt looking. x

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making the database connection in the initialisation of the service itself.

It work in debug because you're not actually starting it as a service:

```
    #if(!DEBUG)
        ServiceBase.Run(new MainClass());
    #else
        MainClass service = new MainClass();
        service.OnStart(new string[0]);
    #endif
```

I suspect that the start method is taking a long time because of this line:

```
    if (_SQLCon.testSQLConnection())
```

You need to make sure that the start method of the service returns in a timely manner and **any** potentially long running process is done in a thread. If you move this test into a thread then you should find it working OK.